# Adding new line with checkbox inside recycler view (like google keep)

Tags: java, android

I have a recyclerview for "steps" list with checkbox and i want to add a new "step" everytime i hit the new line key on keyboard
[Google keep example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNOGY.jpg)

As in the picture, everytime you hit the new line key, a new line with a checkbox automatically appears and is automatically focused.

For now, i have a recycler view with a viewholder that have the checkbox. but i want to know if recyclerview is the best way to do it or there is another way. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom adapter for your recyclerView. This would be easier to handle added functionalities for your checkbox inside recycler view.

Call [notifyItemChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) eachtime your enter a new item in the list.